# How to fix 403 Forbidden error in Postman

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to **scrape** data from atp ranking site:
https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles

So I tried to do a GET on this URL, but I have this error code: "403 Forbidden" with Postman. I don't have this error code on other websites like https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/.

ATP do not have API, so I want to **scrape** the website but it seems **scraping** is not allowed on this website, do you have a solution ?

Thanks

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joFLI.png)

Comment: Check headers require for API request. Might be headers are not included or wrong.

Comment: I tried now with success, so could you share your request's code (curl)?

Comment: @zZzZ 
curl --location --request GET 'https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles' \
--header 'Cookie: __cf_bm=5575863147fa03ef0444721c71d49a3bdbda6fed-1621779433-1800-Afry8f3aioauG9g6sdIroLT2pHx8nqfzaY4ZTtOSNmhViJa2t26sogxS/Ia3VJ11OgsQKvrdUn5dkJMyfk/KNmt5mvYVZ6+4Cf1rI/8ONtqt'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I don't know the headers to be included in the request.

Sometimes it works in Postman but i still get the error in my express JS application:

```
  config: {
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
    transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.1'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 6,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'www.atptour.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'www.atptour.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 13,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'GET /en/rankings/singles HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.18.1\r\n' +
      'Host: www.atptour.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'fifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/en/rankings/singles',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 403,
      statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'www.atptour.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: {
      date: 'Fri, 21 May 2021 18:27:42 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'cf-chl-bypass': '1',
      'permissions-policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
      expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'cf-request-id': '0a31c7fa700000ee0f36b38000000001',
      'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '652fdc3d7c82ee0f-CDG'
    },
    config: {
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Object],
      transformResponse: [Object],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /en/rankings/singles HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.18.1\r\n' +
        'Host: www.atptour.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/en/rankings/singles',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'www.atptour.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
```